# ETW Provider stopped working

Tags: windows, trace, etw

we are using ETW for tracing activities in our applications. when server applications are under heavy work, and we start tracing with our runtime tracing application, sometimes our provider doesn't work. and restarting tracing application and server application doesn't help , and only solution was to restart windows server! I tried xperf and logman commands like `stop` or `delete` which had other problems (we coudn't delete a provider after stopping it and direct delete wasn't possible because "data collector was running").

how can we fix it without restarting the Windows? does etw has any command for resetting all logs?

Comment: please post some pictures of the errors when you run into this again. I have no idea what your issue is.

Comment: there is not any error , Some providers stopped working . and i do not get any event in my tracing application on that providers that i enabled them for tracing .

Comment: run your app in a debugger and always call this.IsEnabled() before calling WriteEvent to make sure someone listens to the provider and set a breakpoint at this.IsEnabled(). When this is false, no tool listens to your provider.

Comment: I know that but first problem is we are in production environment and we can not debug there. second is that we can not recreate that situation in our development systems . and they are not only customers with that problem others with same heavy work has that .problem too .

Comment: how do you capture the events? Via xperf? Try to increase the buffersize.

Comment: we implemented a custom viewer with WPF c# .net. yes we can try it, but is it help us in long time ? and is that size will fill eventually? i was looking for a way that when we have these problem how we can reset all etw activities or some of providers by command or code, thanks anyway.

Comment: How do you capture the events? With TraceEvent? Do you capture them in realtime or write them into a temporary ETL file and parse this one?